# Dynamically link a css

Tags: javascript, html, css

My folder structure look like below:

```
|--js
  |-- main.js
|--css
  |--main.css
|--Folder1
  |-- c.html
|--Folder2
  |-- d.html
|--a.html
|--b.html
```

All the html file will be linked to the main.js and I have something like below in the js to dynamically link the main.css but this only work for html a and b. For html c and d, it expect the css folder is within the same folder.

```
var theorigin = window.location.origin;
var thefile = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
var folder = window.location.pathname.replace(thefile, "");
var newdest = theorigin + folder;

var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = newdest + "../css/main.css";
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Anyone know how to achieve that? Dynamically link the css to the html regardless the folder?

Note: I know I can link the css in the html that put inside a folder by doing this`<link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />`, but for some reason I dont want to do that.

Comment: Isn't `newdest + "../css/main.css` already an absolute url?

Comment: why not use `/css/main.css` to link from the root which for every html file will be the same path.

Answer (score 2):

Just Use below code. its directly point to root (/).

```
link.href = "/css/main.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made the code overly complicated. Why not just:

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "/css/main.css";
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```